# Repository pattern: Dynamic class generation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, templates, orm, t4

I would like to implement the repository pattern, having my domain classes being independent from my repository implementation.

but maintain my domain classes -on schema updates using EF for example- is really expensive.

Do you know someway to automatize domain classes updates based on the ORM classes? -using T4 templates or something similar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i don't know if you are working with EF 4, but in that case Poco templates have recently been released [on the Ado.Net Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2010/01/25/announcing-the-entity-framework-poco-template-update-for-visual-studio-2010-beta-2.aspx)

Comment: Wow This was totally new for me. Thank you very much Luhmain : )

Altough I need an automatized way to generate POCO's totally independent from the repository.

This could works very well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a tool like [Automapper](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/01/22/automapper-the-object-object-mapper.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. : )

But my question is more related to how maintain my domain classes updated based in another set of classes, than map values between different classes.

Something like GAS3 for Flex and java : )

Thanks again.

Comment: I see. Fair enough, but wouldn't that be kind of pointless? (in a 'domain-driven' way)